# How to bypass .htaccess protection?

Tags: authentication, web-application, apache

Is there any way to bypass a directory that protected by .htaccess file?

I played a challenge in CTF and I could not access the path where the flag is.
I tried to access `http://www.example.com/flag` in a challenge but I can't bypass the .htaccess protection.

I tried to read the .htpasswd file but that was forbidden and I tried to use:
`http://ip/~username/flag` but that also did not work.

Comment: It's very vague. Normally you can not bypass .htaccess in case of properly configured apache (certainly, what is the purpose otherwise?). Local processes with adequate rights can access htaccess and your flag. You should provide additional info about the setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use other HTTP Method than GET or POST to access the page ?

Some misconfiguration in Apache could lead to accept request using method like PUT for example.

Try this :

```
curl -X PUT http://www.example.com/flag
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access a file client-side you might be able to access it by compromising another file/script and trying [local file inclusion](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Local_File_Inclusion) to view it.

If you update your questions we can provide more info, but its a bit broad to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: no local file inclusion or sql injection in website to try read the htpasswd with it